# Copy files to multiple computers over LAN

Tags: ssh, command-line, scp, file-copy

Good day, I am pretty new to Unix and I need to do this simple task.

I have a few files, let's name them file01, file02, file03 etc. and I need to copy each of them to one computer from a list. The list of nodes is in a text file. I could do that in a bash script but I think there could be a simpler solution, maybe using xargs?

Here is what I need to do

```
scp file{01...XX} user@(server from servers.txt):~/
```

I hope my problem is clear and thanks for answers.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you need:

```
xargs -I{} scp file{01...XX} user@{}:~/ < servers.txt
```

Comment: I'll be able to test this later today, but doesn't it copy all the files to every server in servers.txt? What I need is to copy file01 to 1. server, file02 to 2. server and so on.

Comment: @user2715488 please would you update your question with this additional requirement

Comment: @user2715488 unless the files are quite literally called `file01`, `file02`, etc., how is the mapping done?

Answer (score 1):

```
for Host in `cat servers.txt` ; do scp file* $Host: ; done
```